# Is there an expression similar to this Portuguese phrase?

Tags: expressions

There's an expression in Portuguese "para você não dizer que eu sou ruim/mau", which literally translates to "in order for you not to say that I'm bad/evil", where "you" or "I" can be replaced by "him/he", "her/she", a specific person and so on. I think it'll be more clear if I use two dialogue examples:

Son: Can you give me some money, Mom?
Mother: Why should I? You spent all you had, last week.
Son: But Mom... Please.
Mother: Ok, **"in order for you not to say I'm bad"**, I'll give you 15 dollars. But don't go spending it with useless things!

Second dialogue:

Boy: Hey, will you watch his match tomorrow? He said he'll be playing and really wanted you to go.
Girl: Well, I don't like sports very much, but **"in order for him not to say I'm bad"**, I'll go watch the first half.

Remember that I'm translating literally the expression - my question is: is there a similar valid expression in English?

Comment: Valeu, cara, manda mais.

Answer (score 2):

For a somewhat literal translation, I would suggest:

- "Here you are, but only because I don't want to be labeled a scrooge."
- "Ok, I'm going to see him play. But I'm doing it only because I don't want him to think I don't care."

A more literary construction might be:

- "Ok, Ok, here you are. but I'm only doing it because I'm a nice guy/dad/mom.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly common phrase, *[against my better judgment](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/against+better+judgement)*, which is used when reluctantly taking an action to appease someone.

*TheFreeDictionary.com*

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to express that sentiment in idiomatic English, but there is not a particularly common phrase that says everything you're trying to say. The closest would probably be something like **for the sake of our friendship** or **to keep the peace.** You would use these when you were giving in, but making it clear that it was only for the asker's sake.

For example:

> I hate sports, but for the sake of our friendship, I'll go to your game anyway.
>
> You had your allowance already, but just to keep the peace I'll give you another five bucks.

Answer (score 1):

An often used phrase is:

> *Just so you can't say I never...*

In your example:

> Son: Can you give me some money, Mom?
>   Mother: Why should I? You spent all you had, last week.
>   Son: But Mom... Please.
>   Mother: Ok. *Just so you can't say I never gave you anything*, here's 15 dollars. But don't go spending it on useless things!